# Strawberry Perl CPAN cannot find path specified

Tags: cpan, strawberry-perl

```
C:\MyPerl>cpan install Parallel::ForkManager
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
Reading '\c\Users\Locals\.cpan\Metadata'
  Database was generated on Wed, 25 Jul 2018 22:55:14 GMT
Running install for module 'Parallel::ForkManager'
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.081)
Checksum for \c\Users\Locals\.cpan\sources\authors\id\Y\YA\YANICK\Parallel-ForkManager-1.20.tar.gz ok
The system cannot find the path specified.
Uncompressed \c\Users\Locals\.cpan\sources\authors\id\Y\YA\YANICK\Parallel-ForkManager-1.20.tar.gz successfully
Using Tar:/usr/bin/tar xf "Parallel-ForkManager-1.20.tar":
The system cannot find the path specified.
Couldn't untar Parallel-ForkManager-1.20.tar: child exited with value 1
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v1.26)
YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-1.20.tar.gz
Had problems unarchiving. Please build manually
```

What am I doing wrong? I have uninstalled and reinstalled Strawberry Perl multiple times, used the MSI installer, and now im trying to zip file. Why the hell is it creating a folder on my C drive called "C"? "C:\c\Users\Locals.cpan\"

Answer (score 2):

I'm sad to be coming with an answer so late, but I ran into the exact same problem and, after some tinkering, have figured it out.

Notice something familiar about that path syntax? It's the one used by MSYS/MinGW/Git Bash. What happened is that, on MinGW, I replaced my home folder with a symlink to my Windows home folder in `/c/Users/<username>/.cpan`. Hence, when I launched CPAN in MinGW, it created my configuration in `/c/Users/<username>/.cpan`, and filled it with with paths in this format.

Now, from Strawberry Perl's point of view, this means I have an existing CPAN configuration in `C:\Users\<username>\.cpan`. Although this is not where CPAN for Strawberry Perl writes its configuration (at least not by default), if a CPAN configuration exists in this path, it will read and write to it instead of the default location. Of course, none of the paths in this configuration makes sense in a Windows context.

Therefore:

- If you use MinGW, Git Bash, Cygwin or any other UNIX-like environment for
  Windows and configured it to use your Windows home folder as your UNIX home folder, undo this configuration.
- Rename, move, or if you're sure you don't need it anymore, delete
  `C:\Users\<username>\.cpan`. You can probably move this directory from your Windows home folder to your UNIX home folder to as to preserve the configuration and modules in your UNIX-like environment. I would advise testing it out.
- Run CPAN in Strawberry Perl again. It will auto-configure itself properly.

Comment: This helped me fix same issue. I had install .cpan previously in my Windows $HOME, and it was interfering with StrawberryPerl. I deleted both .cpan directories, started from scratch, and everything worked fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample output with the latest version of Strawberry Perl x64 which appears to have been successful:

```
C:\Strawberry\perl\bin>cpan install Parallel::ForkManager
Loading internal logger. Log::Log4perl recommended for better logging
CPAN: CPAN::SQLite loaded ok (v0.211)
CPAN: LWP::UserAgent loaded ok (v6.34)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
CPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.70)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/02packages.details.txt.gz
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/modules/03modlist.data.gz
Creating database file ...
Done!
Running install for module 'Parallel::ForkManager'
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/Y/YA/YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.
tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v6.02)
Fetching with LWP:
http://cpan.strawberryperl.com/authors/id/Y/YA/YANICK/CHECKSUMS
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.081)
Checksum for C:\STRAWB~1\cpan\sources\authors\id\Y\YA\YANICK\Parallel-ForkMan
r-2.02.tar.gz ok
CPAN: Archive::Tar loaded ok (v2.30)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta::Requirements loaded ok (v2.140)
CPAN: Parse::CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: CPAN::Meta loaded ok (v2.150010)
CPAN: Module::CoreList loaded ok (v5.20180622)
Configuring Y/YA/YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.02.tar.gz with Makefile.PL
Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Generating a gmake-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Parallel::ForkManager
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
  YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.02.tar.gz
  C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL -- OK
Running make for Y/YA/YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.02.tar.gz
cp lib/Parallel/ForkManager/Child.pm blib\lib\Parallel\ForkManager\Child.pm
cp lib/Parallel/ForkManager.pm blib\lib\Parallel\ForkManager.pm
  YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.02.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe -- OK
Running make test
"C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe" "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness"
e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')"
*.t
t/00-compile.t ............ ok
t/00-load.t ............... 1/4 # time: 1 seconds
t/00-load.t ............... 2/4 # time: 21 seconds
# time: 0 seconds
# time: 2 seconds
t/00-load.t ............... ok
t/00-report-prereqs.t ..... #
# Versions for all modules listed in MYMETA.json (including optional ones):
#
# === Configure Requires ===
#
#     Module              Want Have
#     ------------------- ---- ----
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any 7.34
#
# === Build Requires ===
#
#     Module              Want Have
#     ------------------- ---- ----
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any 7.34
#
# === Test Requires ===
#
#     Module              Want     Have
#     ------------------- ---- --------
#     ExtUtils::MakeMaker  any     7.34
#     File::Spec           any     3.74
#     IO::Handle           any     1.39
#     IPC::Open3           any     1.20
#     Test::More          0.94 1.302136
#     Test::Warn           any     0.35
#
# === Test Recommends ===
#
#     Module         Want     Have
#     ---------- -------- --------
#     CPAN::Meta 2.120900 2.150010
#
# === Runtime Requires ===
#
#     Module     Want     Have
#     ---------- ---- --------
#     Carp        any     1.50
#     File::Path  any     2.15
#     File::Spec  any     3.74
#     File::Temp  any   0.2304
#     Moo         any 2.003004
#     Moo::Role   any 2.003004
#     POSIX       any     1.84
#     Storable    any     3.11
#     strict      any     1.11
#     warnings    any     1.42
#
t/00-report-prereqs.t ..... ok
t/01-utf8-all.t ........... skipped: This is a bug in perl itself on Windows
t/02-callback.t ........... # This test can take 10-20 seconds, please wait.
rted at Wed Oct 17 12:28:28 2018
t/02-callback.t ........... ok
t/03-callback-data.t ...... # This test can take 2-6 seconds, please wait. St
ed at Wed Oct 17 12:28:45 2018
t/03-callback-data.t ...... ok
t/basic-methods.t ......... ok
t/changing-pids.t ......... ok
t/start_child.t ........... ok
t/waitpid-conflict.t ...... # code outside of P::FM stole -3648
child process '-3648' disappeared. A call to `waitpid` outside of Parallel::F
Manager might have reaped it.
t/waitpid-conflict.t ...... ok
t/waitpid-waitonechild.t .. # code outside of P::FM stole -5312
t/waitpid-waitonechild.t .. ok
t/waitpid_blocking.t ...... ok
All tests successful.

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/waitpid-conflict.t    (Wstat: 0 Tests: 2 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   1-2
t/waitpid-waitonechild.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 3 Failed: 0)
  TODO passed:   2-3
Files=12, Tests=28, 70 wallclock secs ( 0.09 usr +  0.00 sys =  0.09 CPU)
Result: PASS
  YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.02.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe test -- OK
Running make install
Installing C:\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\Parallel\ForkManager.pm
Installing C:\STRAWB~1\perl\site\lib\Parallel\ForkManager\Child.pm
Appending installation info to C:\STRAWB~1\perl\lib/perllocal.pod
  YANICK/Parallel-ForkManager-2.02.tar.gz
  C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\gmake.exe install UNINST=1 -- OK
```

I think the problem may be you're just not running cpan from your `\perl\bin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

I installed via the `.msi` installer to a custom location, but for some reason the path didn't get reconfigured internally. `Cpan` continued downloading to `C:\straberry`, even if there was no Perl installation there.

Luckily, this is what the `relocation.pl.bat` is for. Downloading the `.zip` distribution, extracting the batch-file to my Perl installation and running it solved the Problem.

Read the README file that comes with the Perl installation for more information.